# Why does Internet Explorer reject my filename with spaces?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, filenames

I have a bunch of pdf files that have spaces in their name which are displayed in an iFrame as well as in a new window using window.open (not at the same time).

Both work fine in everything except IE8 which throws a file not found error. Remove the spaces and they work fine in IE8.

I need to retain the spaces in the file names so I tried using escape(filename); which repalces the spaces with the escape key %20. This doesn't work either.

I have tried evrything I could think of or could google to make IE8 accept the spaces, but nothing seams to work.

Any suggestions? I can remove the spaces for testing but in the real world removing the spaces from the names of the pdf files in the file system is not currently an option.

Here is the code I am working with

```
var file = "pdfs/this file name has spaces.pdf";
file = escape(file);  //this does not fix the problem

//to display in a new window or tab...
window.open(file);

//to display in my iFrame...
$('.viewer .ifrm').attr('src', file);
```

Thanks.

Comment: show some code (and start accpeting some answers) :)

Comment: How are you displaying the pdf? Also are you decoding the filename before trying to display it?

Comment: I have added the code I am using for this to my question. Josh, what to you mean by "decoding"? I am using the escape function to replace the spaces with escape keys. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Have you tried encoding the spaces as `+`?

Comment: Shaquin - Do you mean to replace the spaces %2B the url encoding reference for the + character?

Comment: I mean replace the spaces with `+`, e.g. `file = file.replace(/ /g, '+');`. Does that work? Also, can you replicate the problem in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? You will have to change `file` to an absolute path to your web server for it to work in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Use encodeURI instead of escape

Comment: I tried, but does not work. I tried it like this... var file = "'file name.pdf'". Is that what you meant?

Comment: encodeURI() does the same thing as escape(), replacing the spaces with %20. Works on everything except IE8. So far the only way I can get it to work is to remove the remove any spaces.

Comment: did you try using a local server or did you open the html+js file directly in your browser ?

Comment: Actually I am testing various ways. Locally in Safari, Firefox, Chrome on Mac OS and IE8 in an XP vm (fusion) with the site served locally on the Mac. I also have the site on a Win 2008 server (windows box) off site. I am also testing in browsers located on a remote windows box connecting to both sites. IE8 fails in all cases.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the Mac site is being served using the Macs external IP address. The Win 2008 server is a domain server. Not sure I have the correct terminology here... to access the Mac server we use xxx.xxx.xxx/misite/index.html on the Win2008 server fubar.com/mysite/index.html.